# append comma separated values to select options jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, each

I have a sting with comma separated

```
var str = "-1,opt1,opt2,opt3,opt4,opt5";
```

I want to append these values to my select dropdown, so that it should look like

```
<select>
   <option value="-1">-Select-</option>
   <option value="opt1">opt1</option>
   <option value="opt2">opt2</option>
   <option value="opt3">opt3</option>
   <option value="opt4">opt4</option>
   <option value="opt5">opt5</option>
</select>
```

I have tried putting the string into my select

```
 $.each(str, function(key, value) { 
    $('#sel').append('<option value="'+value+'">'+key+'</option>');
});
```

Now this will put each string as an option value. But how do i put each opt as one option as i described above.

Comment: `$.each(str.split(','),`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can split the string and then iterate

```js
var str = "-1,opt1,opt2,opt3,opt4,opt5";
$.each(str.split(','), function(key, value) {
  $('#sel').append('<option value="' + value + '">' + (value == '-1' ? 'select' : value) + '</option>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="sel">
</select>
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to `split()` your string in to an array before looping through it:

```js
var str = "-1,opt1,opt2,opt3,opt4,opt5";
$.each(str.split(','), function(key, value) {
    $('#sel').append('<option value="' + value + '">' + key + '</option>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="sel"></select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```js
    var str = "-1,opt1,opt2,opt3,opt4,opt5";
    var strArr = str.split(',');
    var htmlOptions='';
    $(strArr).each(function(index,value){
         htmlOptions += '<option value="'+value+'">' +(value==-1 ? '--select--' : value) +'</option>';
    });

    $('#sel').html(htmlOptions);
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <select id="sel"></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the string [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) method.

```
var str = "-1,opt1,opt2,opt3,opt4,opt5";
var optionStrings = str.split(',');
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var array = str.split(",");
for (i=0;i<array.length;i++){
  $('#sel').append('<option value="'+array[i]+'">'+array[0]+'</option>');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should try this

```
var array = str.split(",");
for (i=0;i<array.length;i++){
  $('#sel').append('<option value="'+array[i]+'">'+array[0]+'</option>');
}
```